# Sqlite3 Comparing Dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

In Sqlite3,

I have entries in a Table like: 
     ('alice', '1986-10-10');

A persons name, with a date formatted like YYYY-MM-DD.

How would one compare if the MM and the DD are the same (not just comparing 10-10), but comparing
if any value in the table have MM and DD of the same value. Aka, the value in MM and DD are the same.

Comment: `where strftime(field1, '%Y-%m')=strftime(field2,'%Y-%m')`, assuming those are actual date/time fields, and not varchar?

Comment: Yes, they are actual date/time fields.
However, what would field1 and field2 be?
My 'alice' variable is a Varchar called Name. So 
    where strftime(Name, '%Y-%m')=strftime(Name,'%Y-%m')   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query like the following is what you are probably looking for:

```
select * from <table_name> 
where strftime('%m', <datefield>) == strftime('%d', <datefield>);
```

If your `<datefield>` is stored in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, the function `strftime('%m', ..)` will extract the month part, and `strftime('%d', ..)` -- the day part.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Thanks for the help. I still struggle with reading about functions and putting them to practical use. Thanks again!